# How to trim excess space in Bootstrap 4.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am building a chat application using NodeJS sockets.io. The front end is bootstrap 4. I have the following project done so far.

[image]

This is how I want to change it:

[image]

This is how my code looks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hey!</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/chat.css">
  </head>

  <body>
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
                    <span><img src="/img/hey_logo.png" id="logo" class="img-fluid"/></span>
                    <span><p class="white_text_arial_font">Group Messenger!</p></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
                  <span><small id="subtextMessage" class="form-text text-muted">Say Hey! to new beginnings.</small></span>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>    

    <BR><BR>

  <div id="rounded_div">

    <form class="" id="chatform" onsubmit="clearTextInput();return false">
      <div class="form-group"> 
        <label class="white_text_arial_font_headers" for="conversationHistory">Conversation History</label>
          <ul class="list-group" id="conversationList">
          </ul>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="white_text_arial_font_headers" for="labelMessage">Type your message</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputMessageTextBox" aria-describedby="inputMessage">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sendMessage()">Send Message</button>
    </form>

  </div>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/chat.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is how my CSS looks:

```
#rounded_div {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: RGB(26,26,27);
    padding: 20px; 
    width: auto;
    height: auto;  
  }

.rounded_div_conversations {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: black;
    padding: 10px; 
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 2px;
  }

#logo {
    display: block;
    max-width: 30%;
    height: auto;
}

body {
    background-color:black;
    text-align:left
}

img {
    margin-right: 0;

}

.white_text_arial_font {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:white;
    margin: 0;
  }

.conversation_texts {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:white;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1;
  }

.white_text_arial_font_headers {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:white;
    margin-bottom: 2;    
  }
```

My question is this: I am from Java world, and in GUI design of Java, there are typically APIs like `pack()` or `hideExcessSpace` which typically does this trimming of the GUI components. But how do I do it in Bootstrap?. Which key word am I looking for doing a search, please let me know.

Please note that I am looking for inputs on the conversation history entries as well as I want the corresponding border for them (  'redzone' text ) to be wrapped as well just like how a message is wrapped in watsapp. So different messages will have different wrapping sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Try .container instead of .container-fluid.